# pyodbc errors do not stop subsequent cell execution in Jupyter Lab notebook

Tags: python, error-handling, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In prior setups, any error in one cell of my notebook would stop all subsequent cells from executing.

Now the notebook continues to execute despite errors in previous cells. I have to check the entire notebook for errors cell by cell.  Is there a way to end the entire execution (without killing the kernel) when an error occurs?

I do not want to create a error script within each cell.

This behavior occurs with programming errors in the SQL code submitted with pyodbc.

I have Jupyter Lab 3.2.1, Python 3.9.7

Comment: Is it specific to a certain notebook? Or does it happen to all of them? Like if you make a brand new notebook it will continue?

Comment: Wayne, It happens in multiple notebooks.   Thank you.

Comment: Is 'multiple' the same as 'all that you've tried'? Brand new ones?

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I tried a brand new notebook.  
I tried to create a couple errors and it did stop processing fine : 
1. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\QBSproject s.xls' where I added a space and 
2. SyntaxError: invalid syntax df2=pd.read_e xcel(open(path,'rb'), sheet_name='QUERY')

Comment: 3. However on 3rd attempt I was able to replicate the behavior of continuing to run.  I introduced a  error in SQL code I am executing through PYODBC.  And the notebook continued to process the rest of the cells. Not sure if that is the only type of error that produces this behavior.

Comment: ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'date'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'E'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'w'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Bh'. (102)")

Comment: In the notebooks that continue to process, if you put in a Python code in a cell below it with an error, it stops on that?

Comment: My thinking is that typical errors do indeed still stop things. So you'd maybe better off making the title of this post more specific or looking around for related information about `pyodbc`. It seems related to SQL use?